# Custom Dialog Fragment Examples

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am sorry for asking this. But I have difficulties in grasping on how to create a custom DialogFragment.

So far I have only managed to create a Custom Dialog. Which is easy to do. Where we simply extends a Dialog class and we set the contentview with our custom layout.

I am wondering if anyone could provide a simple sample of a Custom DialogFragment.

I am looking for a way to create an alert dialog with multiple buttons.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i dont know it will help you or not.Cause i am not clear what type of view you want.But i am giving you a sample code so that you can modify as your wish..I developed for my application for dtmf functionality.Change the image and your layout xml..

```
//DtmfDialogFragment.java

package com.sp.zps.ui;

import com.sp.zps.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockDialogFragment;

public class DtmfDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {


    private static final String EXTRA_CALL_ID = "call_id";
    public static DtmfDialogFragment newInstance(int callId) {
        DtmfDialogFragment instance = new DtmfDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(EXTRA_CALL_ID, callId);
        instance.setArguments(args);
        return instance;
    }



    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(getCustomView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), null, savedInstanceState))
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNeutralButton("Done", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

    EditText dialPadTextView;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    public View getCustomView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.in_call_dialpad, container, false);
        View keyboard = v.findViewById(R.id.dialkeyboard);
        dialPadTextView = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.digitsText);


        ImageButton[] btns = new ImageButton[12];
        setButtonView(btns, keyboard);
        for (final ImageButton btn : btns) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialButtonPressed(v);
                }
            });
        }
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            dialPadTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        }

         return v;
    }

 private void  dialButtonPressed(View v){

     String pressedKey = "";
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button0:
            pressedKey = "0";
            break;
        case R.id.button1:
            pressedKey = "1";
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            pressedKey = "2";
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            pressedKey = "3";
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            pressedKey = "4";
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            pressedKey = "5";
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            pressedKey = "6";
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            pressedKey = "7";
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            pressedKey = "8";
            break;
        case R.id.button9:
            pressedKey = "9";
            break;
        case R.id.buttonstar:
            pressedKey = "*";
            break;
        case R.id.buttonpound:
            pressedKey = "#";
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }

        udpadatePhonePad(pressedKey);
 }

 private void udpadatePhonePad(String pressedkeyVal) {

        int pos = dialPadTextView.getSelectionStart();
        dialPadTextView.getText().insert(pos, pressedkeyVal);

    }
    private void setButtonView(ImageButton[] btns, View keyboard) {

        btns[0] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button0);
        btns[1] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btns[2] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btns[3] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btns[4] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btns[5] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btns[6] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btns[7] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button7);
        btns[8] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button8);
        btns[9] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.button9);
        btns[10] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.buttonstar);
        btns[11] = (ImageButton) keyboard.findViewById(R.id.buttonpound);

    }

}
```

call this fragment like this..

```
DtmfDialogFragment newFragment = DtmfDialogFragment.newInstance(callId);
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Hope it may help you get the correct way..

Comment: Thank you! But may I know what is the@SuppressLint for?

Comment: ah..sorry it for dialPadTextView.setTextIsSelectable()  may be.

Comment: you may not need it for your purpose..take it as a sample brother

Comment: I think that is better, to avoid using of third pary library. You can do the same thing simply extending `android.app.DialogFragment` and overriding `onCreateDialog` you can customize your alert dialog. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) in the section "Alert Dialog"

Comment: Yes but when i used it cause i needed Sherlock lib for my project other functionality and also for supporting lower device.

Comment: Let me know if it helps..

Comment: You don't need Sharlock for supporting lower device. You can use instead the `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` class from the v4 support library. Altought I thing that Sharlok is a good librery, i think that is better to avoid third-party library.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion..I will try to follow you..